# how can I access FaceBook Profile_Picture album using FB graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am accessing FaceBook Developer and I am using **me?fields=albums{picture}** to access the cover photo of my **albums** . How can I go to **profile picture** album ? Basically I want to access the photos of **profile picture** album. Here is an image about what I want to do

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please enter code samples you tried.
You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got the answer with the help of **@CBroe**

to get the album list type :

`me?fields=albums`

after that type your particular album id :

`album_id/photos?fields=source`

to get the photos of that particular album

Comment: That does not limit it to the profile pictures album, it will get you the photos of _all_ albums. (`Profile_Picture` in you query above does nothing at all, you can replace it with `xyz` and you would still get the same result.)

Comment: ok , I saw that as well , then please tell me how do you limit those to `Profile_Picture` only ?

Comment: You need to find the profile pictures album first (list all albums, go through them, check the name), and then request the photos for that specific album id only.

Comment: suppose I am looking for this particular album id, `125287297520173` , what would be request then ?  `me?fields=albums{125287297520173}.fields(Profile_Picture,photos.fields(source))` ??

Comment: No, the album id would be the starting point here, not `me`. `album-id/photos?fields=…` (or `album-id?fields=photos{…}` - but the former syntax requires less nesting.)

Comment: works perfectly , you saved my day @CBroe , thank you so much